# I want to show two results from a single search

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I created a search function for users to find which agent manages their local area.
They type in their local postcode and are delivered a name, phone number and email.
However I now need to add two agents to a single postcode and I cannot get it to work.

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
    return false;
  });
  $("#search-text").keyup(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $("#search-button").click();
    }
  });
});

var array = new Array();

array[0] = ["John Smith", "Phone Number", "john.smith@email.com", ["A", "B", "C"]];
array[1] = ["Bob Jones", "Phone Number", "bob.jones@email.com", ["D", "E", "F"]];
array[2] = ["Harry Up", "Phone Number", "harry.up@email.com", ["D", "E", "F"]];

var errorMessageWrongPostCodeFormat = "Postcode format is incorrect";
var errorMessageNoContactDetailsFound = "No contact details found for this postcode";

//Display Search Results
function searchContactDetails(searchText) {
  var postCodeArea = null;

  //Extract postcode area
  if (searchText.toUpperCase().substring(1, 2) >= "A" && searchText.toUpperCase().substring(1, 2) <= "Z") {
    if (searchText.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1) >= "A" && searchText.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1) <= "Z") {
      postCodeArea = searchText.toUpperCase().substring(0, 2);
    } else {
      document.getElementById('postcode-search-results').innerHTML = '<span class="postcode-search-error">' + errorMessageWrongPostCodeFormat + '</span>';
      return;
    }
  } else {
    if (searchText.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1) >= 'A' && searchText.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1) <= 'Z') {
      postCodeArea = searchText.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1);
    } else {
      document.getElementById('postcode-search-results').innerHTML = '<span class="postcode-search-error">' + errorMessageWrongPostCodeFormat + '</span>';
      return;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i][3].indexOf(postCodeArea) > -1) {
      displayPostCodeSearchResults(array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2]);
      return;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('postcode-search-results').innerHTML = '<span class="postcode-search-error">' + errorMessageNoContactDetailsFound + '</span>';
}

//Display Search Results
function displayPostCodeSearchResults(name, tel, email) {
  document.getElementById('postcode-search-results').innerHTML =
    '<h1>' + name + '</h1><p><a href="tel:' + tel + '" class="body-link">' + tel + '</p><p><a href="mailto:' + email + '" class="body-link">' + email + '</a></p>';
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Hint: Use `filter()`.

Comment: I made you a snippet (I clicked `[<>]` in the editor) and pressed TIDY. Please edit, find "edit above snippet" and add relevant HTML and CSS in a [mcve]

Comment: Also: `$("#search-form").on("submit", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); searchContactDetails($("#search-text").val());
});`

Comment: LASTLY: DRY (Don't repeat yourself). Set a valid boolean and test that where you now have TWO versions of the same error message

Comment: It seems there is an array that contains another arrays. May be https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-array-of-objects-tutorial-how-to-create-update-and-loop-through-objects-using-js-array-methods/ will help you to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some majoring refactoring done here.

Make sure you incrementally update the contents of your result. Also pass a collection to your display function.

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#search-form").submit(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    searchContactDetails($("#search-text").val());
    return false;
  });
  $("#search-text").keyup(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $("#search-button").click();
    }
  });
});

/*Arrays of arrays are horrible to work with
  Use an array of objects instead
*/
var agents = [{
    name: "John Smith",
    phone: "555 789 789",
    email: "john.smith@email.com",
    regions: ["A", "B", "C"]
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Jones",
    phone: "555 456 456",
    email: "Bob.Jones@email.com",
    regions: ["D", "E", "F"]
  },
  {
    name: "Harry Up",
    phone: "555 123 123",
    email: "Harry.Up@email.com",
    regions: ["D", "E", "F"]
  },
];


var errorMessageWrongPostCodeFormat = "Postcode format is incorrect";
var errorMessageNoContactDetailsFound = "No contact details found for this postcode";

//Display Search Results
function searchContactDetails(searchText) {
  var postCodeArea = null;
  let matchedAgents = null;
  let agentFound = false;
  //Extract postcode area
  //If the following is just checkin that the first two charcters are A-Z use a regex instead
  //let prefix = searchText.toUpperCase().substring(0,2);
  /*if (prefix.charAt(1) >= "A" && prefix.charAt(1) <= "Z") && (prefix.charAt(0) >= "A" && prefix.charAt(1) <= "Z") {   
      postCodeArea = prefix;
  } else if (prefix.charAt(0) >= 'A' && prefix.charAt(0) <= 'Z') {
      postCodeArea = prefix.charAt(0);    
  }*/

  //Extract first 1 or 2 charcters if they are alphabetic
  const regex = /^[a-z]{1,2}/i;
  let match = searchText.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    postCodeArea = match[0];

    //Remove previous messages
    $('#postcode-search-results').empty();


    //Iterate the agents
    agents.forEach(agent => {
      //If theres a match
      if (agent.regions.includes(postCodeArea.toUpperCase())) {
        //Call display with the agent object
        displayPostCodeSearchResults(agent);
        //Flag there was a match
        agentFound = true;
      }
    });
  }

  //Check if conditions are met
  if (postCodeArea && agentFound) {
    //If all good remove the error class if it was there previously
    $("#postcode-search-results").removeClass("postcode-search-error")
  } else {
    //If not set the error message and class 
    $("#postcode-search-results").addClass("postcode-search-error").html(!postCodeArea ? errorMessageWrongPostCodeFormat : errorMessageNoContactDetailsFound);
  }


}

//Display Search Results
function displayPostCodeSearchResults(agent) {
  //Use a template literal to append the results.
  $('#postcode-search-results').append(`<h1>${agent.name}</h1><p><a href="tel:${agent.phone}" class="body-link">${agent.phone}</p><p><a href="mailto:${agent.email}" class="body-link">${agent.email}</a></p>`);
}
```

```css
.postcode-search-error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-form">
  <input type="text" id="search-text"><button type="submit" id="search-button">Go</button>
</form>
<div id="postcode-search-results"></div>
```